# PHP assert() function setting undefined to $matches

Tags: php

Any idea why this function would not assign anything to `$matches`?

```
assert(preg_match(SCIENTIFIC_NOTATION_CAPTURING_REGEX,
    $x, $matches));
```

(both values `$x` `SCIENTIFIC_NOTATION_CAPTURING_REGEX` and are defined when running the function)

The function on it self works fine, but on another environment it throws an error because of `$matches` being undefined. I can't figure out whats different that would cause that.

Comment: just a shot in the dark: maybe a custom error_handler that catches the `WARNING` of assert and stops the script?

Comment: _"on another environment"_ means another server? another php version? another script where only that line is pasted into?

Comment: [`assert`](http://php.net/assert) became a language construct starting with PHP 7.0. The contained expression will only run if enabled per php.ini. You cannot rely on a result variable, unless you also check that one in another assert.

Comment: @Jeff It was a different server. Turns out the php.ini variable zend.assertions needed to be set to 1 (Development).. Not comfortable with setting the development mode on assert on in a prod environment so removed the assert functions and using a different way around. Thanks for the help guys.